# Site navigation sits unstyled for a second on page reload

Tags: menus, navigation, css

To clarify a bit - i've styled the main navigation on my site by selecting its class, and going down the hierarchy from there. At a random point in development it started appearing completely stripped of css, as an unordered list, and stayed that way for about a second before getting styled while the rest of the page loads instantly.

Has anyone had similar experiences? How did you approach the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a network latency issue (i.e. the stylesheet taking too long to download). In other forums this is known as a "flash of unstyled content," and has various fixes and approaches to resolve. However, this isn't specific to WordPress, so I'm going to vote to close the question for now. It's a good question, though, and I'd encourage you to keep researching it (perhaps on the main Stack Overflow site) keeping the phrase I mentioned above in mind.

Comment: The site is currently being run locally, and the only item that has a styling problem on load is the nav, the rest of the page loads fine, without any flashes, while the nav stays unstyled for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a flash of unstyled content (FOUC, also flash of unstyled text or FOUT) which is an instance where a web page appears briefly with the browser's default styles prior to loading an external CSS stylesheet, due to the web browser engine rendering the page before all information is retrieved.

It could be caused by many things.  bad scripting, server delay, bad coding, etc.

You could check out a site speed test (google "pingdom site test") and it MAY give you a clue.

Comment: It certainly looks like it, but I'm running the site locally. Everything else loads almost instantly while the navigation stays unstyled (tested in incognito).
Would you still classify it under FOUC or do yo think it might be something else.

Comment: Yes, because that's exactly what's going on. Since it's local, Pingdom and other tools won't be able to reach it. I'd instead use the network panel in your browser's debugger to see how and when resources (stylesheets) are being loaded in the request. This kind of FOUC could happen when a stylesheet is loaded from a slow/remote source or if the styles are defined _after_ the navigation renders (i.e. later in the page or via JavaScript).

Comment: yep.  if it's local. use your browser debugger.  you'll find the culprit.